# Mysql query substract issue

Tags: mysql, subtraction

To begin with I have two tables:

**feeds:(id,content_id,author)** and 
**feeds_ratings:(id,feed_id (FK to feeds(id)),user_id,rating)**

What I want to do is get the total rating difference for a specific author by a certain user.

To explain a bit more, let's say we have three rows in the feeds table, **(1,3245,test),(2,3215,test),(3,3122,test)** and tree rows on the feeds_ratings table, **(1,1,12,like), (1,2,12,like),(1,3,12,dislike)**

The input will be the user_id and the author and I want the output to be the difference between the total dislikes and likes by the input user, for the specific input author. (In this example it will be 1 because of the two likes and the one dislike.

How can that be implemented in a mysql query? I tried searching and some code of my own but I can't make it work, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not provide a sqlfiddle? (This should be a standard requirement.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work using `SUM` with `CASE` -- add 1 for likes and -1 for dislikes:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN fr.rating = 'like' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) TotalLikes
FROM Feeds F
  INNER JOIN Feeds_Ratings FR ON F.id = FR.feed_id
WHERE F.author = 'test' 
  AND FR.user_id = 12
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d833/1)

Obviously replace author and user_id with the appropriate values -- these are just for your sample input.

Comment: Sweet lord that was fast! 
I couldn't figure out how to do the sum part, thanks a lot. I will mark it as accepted in a jiffy.

Comment: @Systemfreak -- np, glad I could help!